# Rename multiple files within subdirectories to part of their parent subdirectory name

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, file-rename

I want to recursively rename multiple files within subdirectories to part of their parent subdirectory name

example from:

```
C:\abc\test1.noxz\wwww.xz  
C:\abc\test2.noxz\ccc.xz
```

example to:

```
c:\abc\test1.noxz\test1.xz  
c:\abc\test2.noxz\test2.xz
```

I've tried a batch file in `C:\abc`, but the result is `test1.noxz.xz`, not `test1.xz`.

```bash
@echo off
@for /r /d %%x in (*) do @for %%y in (xz) do @ren "%%x\*.%%y" "%%~nxx.%%y" 2> NUL
```

What do I need to change to fix this?

Comment: Your examples do not seem to require recursion, please explain your environment better to us. The following without recursion, should provide the results you have laid out in your examples, ```@For /D %%G In (*) Do @For %%H In ("%%G\*.xz") Do @Ren "%%H" "%%~nG%%~xH" 2>NUL```.

Comment: My example above **does not** place `.noxz` in the new file name! The non recursive code I provided, as a single line batch file saved in `C:\abc`, and simply double-clicked in Windows Explorer should do exactly what was expected. Also, there is an [Edit] button; please use it to provide the information in your above comment, and please include information to explain how you yourself are invoking this batch file.

Comment: Your code work for the presented example. But doesn't work if i have sub\subfolders ex: "c:\abc\def\ghi\test3.noxz\kkkk.xz" and i run the bat file from "c:\abc" folder, then the result should be: "c:\abc\def\ghi\test3.noxz\test3.xz". (Windows11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following setting for the directory is a name
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"

FOR /r "%sourcedir%" %%e IN (*.xz) DO (
 FOR %%o IN ("%%~dpe.") DO ECHO REN "%%e" "%%~no%%~xe"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

**Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

The `for /r` command assigns each full filename matching the mask `*.xz` found in the subtree to `%%e`.

`%%~dpe.` will then be the parent directory's name with the terminal backslash removed - which looks like a filename. Select the name part of `%%o` and the extension of `%%e` (which will be `.xz`) to form the new filename.

You could also add `if /i "%%~xo"==".noxz"` between the `do` and `echo` to filter only the subdirectories named `.noxz` (`if /i` = case-insensitive)